# Object trackin in machine vision - track a moving wheel

Tags: computer-vision, video-processing, object-tracking

for a thesis project I have to track the position and the displacement of a moving wheel recorded in a video.
I've read quite a bit about image analysis algorithms, but cannot figure out how to start.
I need some kind of starting point on this matter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**ADDENDUM**

I'll provide some more details on the setup of this application.
I have a high speed camera, fixed with respect to the context, that is recording a single wheel of a landing gear. The setup is simulating the touch down of the wheel of the landing gear, so the wheel is translating and rotating at the same time. I need a way to track the wheel and its rotation.

Following are two frames of the video.

[image]

[image]

Comment: _"I need some kind of starting point"_ You should explain on which part you get stuck. You've read a lot about image analysis but no-one here will know if they are telling you something you already know...

Comment: Hi, I've studied about Image Analysis Algorithms like edge detection, digital morphology, gray level segmentation, content based search, noise reduction, and I've worked a lot with very low level image acquisition and processing like Debayering, image transformation, White balance, vignetting removal, color space rotation and so on. What (I think) l need is to put it all together and find a way to identify an image in a video frame, track it and (since I'm tracking a rotating wheel) also detect it's displacement.

Comment: **(1)** Do you have an example image (a video clip is better)?. Not obvious if your camera moves, or your wheel moves across the screen or wheel is rotating whilst staying in same position (like a wheel testing machine recorded by the camera). Not obvious what pixels you see as input and why you can't get started. **(2)** Consider **block matching** to find the wheel. Consider **optical flow** to track the rotation.

Comment: I've added some details and a couple of frames.

Comment: Do you have to work with pre-recorded data, or would it be possible to attach something like a QR code on the wheel?

Comment: This video is a provided sample, but I guess in a "live" situation I would be able to place markers on the wheel.

Comment: So is block matching & optical flow looking like good options to you? Many demos and visual tutorials on Youtube also. If you segment the frame image into smaller squares (_ie:_ macroblocks), then it's easier to do both things per block area.

Comment: Thank you VC.One, I'm studying (at night...) about block matching and it seems a good starting point. I'll see where it wil ltake me. Thanks